# SignalR client specific with angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

So I am fairly new with signalR and had worked with it a bit with MVCs. Now I am using it in webapi with angularjs and am a bit confused or have forgotten of what I have done. I am using bearer tokens with webapi and am trying to create a notification system.

What I want to figure out is the proper way of using angularjs with signalR. I see many people use the proxy on/invoke. Is the proxy.on is when I call the hubcontext from the server as so:

`IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
 hubContext.Clients.User(UserId).broadcastNotification("Good morning! The time is " + DateTime.Now.ToString());`

and the proxy.invoke method is from the client side? If so, which would be the best way for using notification systems (I would assume the proxy.on)?

My second question is more on sending notifications to specific users. For sending requests to specific users, I would assume you would want to do this on the hub as so:

`public void SendNotification(string userId)
        {
            Clients.User(userId).broadcastNotification("Good morning! The time is " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }`

My startup is something like this:

```
 public class MyProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
        {
            var userId = request.User.Identity.Name;
            return userId.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AuthContext, Travelfy.API.Migrations.Configuration>());
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new MyProvider());
        app.MapSignalR("/hubs", new HubConfiguration());

    }
```

When I refresh my pages, I notice that all my userids are all empty strings "". I was reading that maybe it was due to using bearer tokens. If so, how would I use bearer tokens to specific the userId that I would want to send to? When I use the Clients.All everything works fine, so I'm assuming it has to be something with the startup/userIds I am getting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a while, I was able to figure out the right answer. Because I was using bearerTokens, I really had to determine another method of obtaining the userId rather than just relying on request.User.Identity.Name. What I needed to do was pass my bearerToken to the connection.qs value.

`connection.qs = { Bearer: token };`

Once I was able to do that I had to route the find my user based on the token that I had sent in.

`var token = request.QueryString.Get("Bearer");
            var authenticationTicket = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

> Which would be the best way for using notification systems

If you want to push notifications from the server towards the client, you have to define a new handler is to define a method on the client (with the generated proxy) like this:

[How to define methods on the client that the server can call](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callclient)

If you want the client to call a method that lies on the server, you have to use this method:

[How to call server methods from the client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callserver)

To answer your second question:

> For sending requests to specific users, I would assume you would want
>   to do this on the hub

You could use the `connection ID` of the client you wish to target. See this:

[Calling client methods](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callingclientsoutsidehub)

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at this when I get a chance. Will most likely have more questions.

Comment: I believe my issue is in regards to the Irequest value MyProvider is coming out to be null for the userName and authenticationType. I believe this is because I am using bearer tokens rather than Cookies. How would I get through the userId/userName for Irequest?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. You want  to know how to call the client from the server-side using the connection ID? You can use the `OnConnected()` method in the SignalR hub on the server-side and add the connected client's connection ID to a dictionary using his hostname as the key. Then you can instantiate the hub elsewhere and target specific clients using the connection ID in your dictionary. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My questions are regards to whether it is more reasonable to call your method from a hub instance or the hub class? Additionally if I was using the hub instance, how would I obtain connectionIds and send a notification to the right connectionId? When I just put context.connectionid in the hub class I send it to myself and not to the person I want to send to. In that case would I need to put it in a table and save these connectionIds? In this case I tried using the IUserProvider to return my user info, but my results are always empty.

Comment: You can use a static class that will be like a singleton and contain a dictionary of connectionId's that will be added using the `OnConnected()` method. Then in your controller class you obtain the hubContext by doing : `var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubName>();` Then you can get the connectionId from the dictionary and call a specific client like this: `hub.Clients.Client(connectionId).BroadcastMethod(broadcastMessage);`

Comment: Thanks for that. I was confused with how I can relate my ConnectionId with the UserId, so that I know who I would be sending a notification to. I was trying to add UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() into the OnConneced method of the dictionary class, but when I do I get a null value. Im not sure why you can't call this within the Hub or more why is it null?

Comment: I think I have answered your question so far, It would be really appreciated if you could mark it as an answer. Try to think outside the box. All you need is a static class seperate from your hub and controller that will contain a dictionary.

Comment: Sure thing. but my main question was the second portion about the userIds being empty from the IRequest property not giving me the correct userNames.

Comment: According to this page: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider you are doing it correctly. I dont see what is the problem

Comment: Try moving your `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method to a Startup class and use OWIN to fire it up. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr